# How to get program to display 2 answers if both are the same

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a student who is new to c++ and wondering if there was a way to get my program to display more than 1 answer if they are the same. I am writing a c++ program for a class,using a two dimensional array, as well as several others to track sales amount at a car company. At the end of the program, the salesperson with the most and least amounts as well as the most amount of cars and least amount of cars are displayed. I have the program running mostly correctly, only problem I am having is getting it to display if one of the results has two answers.

My input data is as follows

```
Car         S   A   L   E   S   P   E   R   S   O   N
Model       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   Total   Average
        ________________________________________________________________________________________
1       8   5   2   4   1   1   1   3   ??  ??
2       5   7   2   2   3   4   3   1   ??  ??
3       5   1   1   0   0   0   5   5   ??  ??
4       2   3   2   1   2   2   2   3   ??  ??
5       7   2   0   0   0   1   4   1   ??  ??
6       2   2   2   2   3   4   3   2   ??  ??
7       2   1   2   3   3   1   2   1   ??  ??
8       5   8   1   1   2   1   2   1   ??  ??
9       4   8   2   1   1   2   3   2   ??  ??
10      1   4   4   4   2   4   2   4   ??  ??
__________________________________________________________________________
Total       ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??      
Average ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??  ??      ??
```

based on the data, car models 5 and 7 sold the least , so 2 answers need to be displayed.
based on the data sales people 1 and 2 sold the most so again there needs to be 2 answers displayed.

would anyone be able to advise me or give me a little help with this part?

---

```
// Lab09car.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream InFile;
    int CarModel;
    int NumCarModels = 10;
    double CarModelSum[10], SalesPersonSum[8];
    double CarModelAvg[10], SalesPersonAvg[8];
    double CarModelAverage;
    int SalesPerson;
    int NumSalesPerson = 8;
    int CarModelCount = 0;
    int MaxModel, MinModel, MaxSalesPerson, MinSalesPerson;
    InFile.open("E:/CSC133-01/CSC133LabAssignments/Lab09/Lab09inp.dat");
    double CarSales[12][10];
    int TotalTotals{};
    double TotalAverages{};

    cout << "\n________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "\n \t\t  Automobile Sales Report For The Month Of June";
    cout << "\n \t\t __________________________________________________";
    cout << "\n \t\t Report Prepared By: " << endl;
    cout << "\n Car \t\t\t\t SALESPERSON";
    cout << "\n Model \t 1\t 2\t 3\t 4\t 5\t 6\t 7\t 8\t Total\t Average";
    cout << "\n________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;


    //reads data into matrix from file
    for (CarModel = 0;CarModel < NumCarModels; CarModel++)
        {
            for (SalesPerson = 0;SalesPerson < NumSalesPerson;SalesPerson++)
            {
                InFile >> CarSales[CarModel][SalesPerson];
            }
        }

    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) 
    {
        CarModelSum[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0;j < 8;j++)
            CarModelSum[i] += CarSales[i][j];
            CarModelAvg[i] = (CarModelSum[i] * 1.0) / 8;
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++) 
    {
        SalesPersonSum[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0;j < 10;j++)
        SalesPersonSum[i] += CarSales[j][i];
        SalesPersonAvg[i] = (SalesPersonSum[i] * 1.0) / 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        cout << "\n " << (i + 1);
        for (int j = 0;j < 8;j++)
        cout<<setprecision(0) << "\t " << CarSales[i][j];
        cout << " \t " << CarModelSum[i] << "\t " << fixed << setprecision(2) << CarModelAvg[i];
    }
    cout << "\n________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout << "\n Total ";
    for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++) 
    {
        cout << "\t " <<setprecision(0)<< SalesPersonSum[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        TotalTotals += SalesPersonSum[i];
    }
    cout << "\t" << setw(4)<< TotalTotals;
    cout << "\n Average ";
    for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << SalesPersonAvg[i] << "\t ";
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++)
    {
        TotalAverages += SalesPersonAvg[i];
    }
    TotalAverages = TotalAverages / 8;
    cout << "\t"<<setw(5)<<TotalAverages;

    MaxModel =0, MinModel = 0;
    for (int i = 1;i < 10;i++)
    {
        if (CarModelSum[i] > CarModelSum[MaxModel])
            MaxModel = i;
        if (CarModelSum[i] < CarModelSum[MinModel])
            MinModel = i;
    }
    MaxSalesPerson = MinSalesPerson = 0;
    for (int i = 1;i < 8;i++)
    {
        if (SalesPersonSum[i] > SalesPersonSum[MaxSalesPerson])
            MaxSalesPerson = i;
        if (SalesPersonSum[i] < SalesPersonSum[MinSalesPerson])
            MinSalesPerson = i;
    }
    cout << "\n________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
    cout <<setprecision(0)<< "\n The Car Model that sold the most number of cars is the Model " << (MaxModel + 1) << ". There were " << CarModelSum[MaxModel] << " sold";
    cout << "\n The Car Model that sold the least number of cars is the Model " << (MinModel + 1) << ". There were " << CarModelSum[MinModel] << " sold";
    cout << "\n The Salesperson who sold the most number of cars is " << (MaxSalesPerson + 1) << ". That person sold " << SalesPersonSum[MaxSalesPerson] << " cars";
    cout << "\n The Salesperson who sold the least number of cars is " << (MinSalesPerson + 1) << ". That person sold " << SalesPersonSum[MinSalesPerson] << " cars";
    cout << "\n________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Instead of storing the index of the `MaxModel`, store the actual value. Then, in another loop, print all models with that value.

Comment: what exactly would I do. sorry long day of doing this, boards in my head are getting fried haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the index of the `MaxModel`, store the actual value. Then, in another loop, print all models with that value.

```
MaxModel = CarModelSum[0], MinModel = CarModelSum[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 10;i++) {
    if (CarModelSum[i] > MaxModel)
        MaxModel = CarModelSum[i];
    if (CarModelSum[i] < MinModel)
        MinModel = CarModelSum[i];
}
```

Then, print the ones that match:

```
cout << "The Car Model(s) that sold the most number of cars: ";
for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
    if (CarModelSum[i] == MaxModel) {
        cout << i << " "
    }
}
cout << endl << "There were " << MaxModel << " sold each";
```

And do the same for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you may need two loops. For example:car models 5 and 7 sold the least , so 2 answers need to be displayed. First of all we should need to get the value "a" of the least sales . And then we will get car models 5 and 7 sold the least.

Here is a simple code: We enter a set of data ,like{1,2,3,4,3,2,5,1,2,3,}. We can get the minimum value is "1". And then we can get the sequence of corresponding numbers "1" is "0" and "7"

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int  min;
    int  min_n;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    min = a[0]; 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] <= min) { min = a[i]; min_n = i; }
    }


    cout << "min=" << min <<  endl;


    cout << "——————————————————————" << endl;


    int *p;
    p = a;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (*p == min)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
        p++;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Hope this code is helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i was able to get desired results